# Read a JPEG image from memory with boost::gil

Tags: c++, boost, jpeg, boost-gil

I am trying to read an image from memory by using `boost::gil` present in boost 1.53. I have taken the following lines from an example taken from internet:

```
#include <boost/gil/gil_all.hpp>
boost::gil::rgb8_image_t img;
boost::gil::image_read_settings<jpeg_tag> readSettings;
boost::gil::read_image(mystream, img, readSettings);
```

Except the first line, the type and function in the remaining lines cannot be found in the `boost::gil` namespace, so I cannot test if the above lines do what I want. Do you have any idea where to get the required types and functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the new version of gil here: [gil stable version](http://code.google.com/p/gil-contributions/source/browse/trunk/gil_2.zip)

It works well and it is stable.

```
using namespace boost::gil;
image_read_settings<jpeg_tag> readSettings;
rgb8_image_t newImage;
read_image(stream, newImage, readSettings);
```

You code seems correct.

Answer (score 4):

Boost 1.68, which is [planned for release on 8th of August, 2018](https://www.boost.org/development/index.html), will finally deliver the new Boost.GIL IO (aka IOv2) [reviewed and accepted long time ago](https://lists.boost.org/boost-announce/2011/01/0281.php).
It is already available from the current `master` branch of the Boost super-project (check Boost.GIL [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/boostorg/gil/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) for guidelines how to work with the super-project).

Now, you can use GIL from Boost 1.68 or later, here is example that shows how to read image from input stream. It does not have to be file-based stream, but any `std::istream`-compatible stream should work.

```
#include <boost/gil.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/io/io.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "input jpeg file missing\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    try
    {
        std::ifstream stream(argv[1], std::ios::binary);

        namespace bg = boost::gil;
        bg::image_read_settings<bg::jpeg_tag> read_settings;
        bg::rgb8_image_t image;
        bg::read_image(stream, image, read_settings);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: if you don't need read_settings then you don't need to pass to read_image().

Comment: Correct. I just left it to keep the example similar to @Hussem Bdr -s answer.